# Selenium cannot connect to localhost for testing ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, testing, localhost

I'm writing GUI tests for an ASP.NET web application but Selenium can not seem to connect to the localhost.  Every time I run the test case it loads the chrome browser, but I get the error "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".  I can connect to the localhost just fine for development, just not testing.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace MyApplication.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    { 
        [TestMethod]
        public void ButtonMenuDimensions_Chrome()
        {
            try
            {
                String url = "http://localhost:52956";
                ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                String actualHeight = driver.FindElement(By.Id("menu")).GetCssValue("height");
                Console.WriteLine("Actual Height: " + actualHeight);
                String expectedHeight = "450px";
                String actualWidth = driver.FindElement(By.Id("menu")).GetCssValue("width");
                String expectedWidth = "200px";

                Assert.AreEqual(expectedHeight, actualHeight);
                Assert.AreEqual(expectedWidth, actualWidth);

                driver.Close();
                driver.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error executing test case: Dimensions");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I open up the output for this test case I am getting

```
Error executing test case: Dimensions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're running the app on iis express, you will need to make sure this is running when your test are by having the ASP website running/debugging in VS.

If you hit the URL http://localhost:52956 without running the ASP website can you still hit it?

Comment: Thank you very much!  I figured that the Tests would be able to start the IIS Server on their own.  Unfortunately VS does not let you run tests while the website is running/debugging so you have to load up two different instances of Visual Studio, one to start the server and the other to run the tests.

Comment: Surely there must be a way to get the unit tests to run the website?